# Google+ share image (not full album) via public URL?

Tags: google-plus

In Picasa Web, you could get a public link to individual images that you had set to public.  But in Google+ I can't figure out how to get a public link for an image. I can only get a link to a public album.

How can I get a public link to an individual image? Is it possible? It was always very helpful for things like, posting an image on Craigslist or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 3**
Looks like they changed the context-menu behavior back to my original answer! i've removed the alternate solution because this is the best answer, but I've saved it in case it goes away again :) Anyway, original answer below:

If you right-click on the image and select "Copy image URL" it should copy the public URL to your clipboard.

Likewise, you can right-click on an image and select "Open image in new tab." The URL you go to should be publicly shareable.

Comment: I feel silly I didn't realize that. Thanks! Although in Picasa you could pick from multiple URLs for different sizes of the image. But this works good enough. Thanks!

Comment: Am I missing something or has Google disabled the ability to use the above fix? I was using this regularly and as recently as last week but, today, I can no longer get the link to individual photos.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I tried it now and it looks like the ability to view single images has been disabled. I updated my answer to include a really horrible solution, but it'll work :(

Comment: I just tried the initial solution - "Copy image URL" - and it worked fine. Maybe this is about different ways of accessing Google+ images?

Comment: Gah, they changed the behavior back to include the image options in the menu. I've updated the answer (again)!

Answer (score 0):

The right click "copy image URL" was working 3 days ago and I used it regularly in Chrome, the only other option I use is to right click the image in IE, select properties, and copy the address (URL) section (I triple click the address and hit ctrl-c)

Comment: This is pretty much the same answer as @OnenOnlyWalter's first Update.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution if you use Google Photos (G+ similar) - 09.10.2015

1. open Google Photos in browser  & share item
2. generate share link
3. open shared link in browser
4. click on image
5. second time right click on image (select copy image address - chrome)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]